# Simulating form submit with a jquery ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I have a chunk of code that defines `div`s and some of the callbacks on them when clicked. To avoid code redundancy, I want to reuse it. The callbacks use `$.post` calls to communicate with the server whereas, for this specific page, I want a page refresh the way a form submit does.

Is there any difference in using a form submit to `submitPage.php` and using the following?

```
$.post('submitPage',  dataParams, null, 'json').
      success(function(resp, status, req) {
        window.location = 'submitPage.php';  // redirect
      });
```

I am curious about how this might intrinsically effect the processing of entries in `dataParams` by submitPage.php.

Comment: the only difference i see it there will not be a post back event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is that when you submit a form normally, the page request also has the data serialized along with it. You are submitting the form as an AJAX request and then redirecting the user to a page without the serialized form data attached.

So if you need the `$_POST` variable to be accessible on the `submitPage.php` then I would let the form submit normally rather than hi-jacking the submit with an AJAX request and then redirecting the user.

You could add the `$_POST` data to the `$_SESSION` and then use that when you redirect the user but unless you have a reason to do that it seems like an unnecessary bit of code.

Comment: So, the processing on the data happens when the server processes the post request. After that, I don't need reprocessing. So not sending data the second time might be ok right? Would this work out?

Comment: @Navneet The issue I could see happening is that `submitPage.php` uses `$_POST` variables to populate itself with data, if that's the case then when you redirect the user these variables will not be there for the `submitPage.php` page.

Comment: I see that problem. Was using isset() to check but I am starting to get the feeling that might be too hacky a solution. :)